# Client Web Service call over SSL using Apache Axis

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I'm using Apache Axis 1.5.1 to code a web service client connecting to a service over SSL. My application is running in Tomcat with SSL configuration setup in JKS. However, when I connect to the server, the connection is failing because the cert from our client is not being sent to the server. Is this something that has to be set in the client through code? Also note that the server does not need any user name or password authentication. With SSL turned off, everything works fine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Two common approaches here:
http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/ssl.html
WebLogic has its own stuff:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/security/SSL_client.html#wp1029670

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the certificates configured correctly in your trust store accessible to Tomcat, there are no changes to Apache Axis HTTP code.